# If $∇f(a)\cdot y ≤ 0$ for every vector $y$, why does $\nabla f(a)$ have to be zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

If $f$ is differentiable at every point in $B(a)$ and $f(x)≤f(a)$ for all $x$ in $B(a)$, prove that $∇f(a)=0$.

I actually did some work and found out that $∇f(a)\cdot y ≤ 0$ for every vector $y$.

But, can't understand $∇f(a)·y ≤ 0$ for every vector $y$, why does $∇f(a)$ have to be $0$?

This is just part of proof that I am not sure about.

Comment: Take $y$ to be the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, $\nabla f(a)\cdot\nabla f(a)\leq0$.

Comment: So, we can take y as gradient of f, and it is contradiction..

Comment: No contradiction. If $\nabla f(a)\cdot y\le0$ for every vector $y$, then in particular the statement holds for $y=\nabla f(a)$. Thus $0\le\|\nabla f(a)\|^2=\nabla f(a)\cdot\nabla f(a)\le0$, so $\|\nabla f(a)\|=$ and hence $\nabla f(a)=0$.